# Plot the Power Spectral Density for a signal in Matlab

Tags: signal-analysis, power-spectral-density, signal-power

I have an OFDM signal `x`, generated using QAM modulation, I first use the command in matlab `y1 = ifft(x);` to generate the time-domain signal. Then when I plot the PSD, I get that figure in the right of below picture. On the other hand, when I generate the time-domain signal using `y2 = F’*x`;  where `F = dftmtx(N)/sqrt(N)`; and `N` is the length of subcarriers,   I get the PSD plot as shown on the left of picture!
However (y1 – y2) is almost 0,  why do we get that difference ? Which one is correct?
NP: What is strange for me is the difference between the two ways however the signal is the same.

[image]

Comment: @DanBoschen  I am asking why do I get that difference.  However i almost use the same way to plot the PSD ..  The way of ploting the PSD is OK and I agree with the explanation you shared,  but I couldn't understand  the difference shown above.

Comment: @Sajjad It looks like on the right-hand side you're plotting only half the spectrum.

Comment: @DanBoschen I only use `ifft(x)`, I don't use what you mentioned `y1 = ifftshift (ifft(x))`.

Comment: @MBaz but also y axis is different, the right one is between 20 - 40 while the other one between 0 - 60.

Comment: @DanBoschen Ok I will check it, but I am still wondering about the above figures, why do I get the difference however the signal is the same ? !

Comment: @DanBoschen by the way I used the way you mentioned, `y1 = ifftshift (ifft(x))` , I get the same result, nothing has been changed,

Comment: @DanBoschen `Pxx=periodogram(x);
Hpsd=dspdata.psd(Pxx,'Fs',1.0000e+09); 
plot(Hpsd);`  I use this code to plot the PSD. 2-  the signal x is real  because I am using [0 x 0 flipud(conj(x))]; iso the output of ifft becomes real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the OP is using the MATLAB/Octave `periodogram(X)` function to plot the power spectral density and this function will return different results depending on if `X` is real or complex. When `X` is real-values, a one-sided spectrum will be estimated, but if `X` is complex-valued, or the optional 'RANGE" parameter is used to specify "twosided", then a full spectrum will be estimated.

For the one on the right, the data was truly real, and we get a one-sided spectrum result (although the frequency specified is twice as high). For the one on the left, the data was complex, even though the imaginary values were significantly small. The periodogram recognized the complex values and returns a two-sided spectrum as on the left.

Comment: Can you send code here for the psd? I need to plot psd in this way but don't know how just plot it using fft.